# How to remove an empty interface type from an item type in an array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface EmptyObject {}

interface TypeA {
  type: 'A';
}

interface TypeB {
  type: 'B';
}

type ItemType = EmptyObject | TypeA | TypeB;

type IArray = (ItemType | null)[] | undefined;
```

These are generated types, the problem here is the ItemType which is an union, and always comes with an EmptyObject type, we can not control the source, so I am thinking:

1. is it possible to write a utility type to remove the `EmptyObject` from `IArray`? Which is nested 1 level down. I know how to remove `EmptyObject` from `ItemType`, but do not know how to remove it from `IArray`
2. or could we write a function such that we can do something like `const listOfTypeAorTypeB = getItems(array: IArray)`, which in this case, the `listOfTypeAorTypeB`  only contains `TypeA` o `TypeB`?
3. or a function to `const listofTypeA = getItems(array: IArray)`, which only gets TypeA here.

The constraints are:

1. the `getItems()` should be generic enough, so we do not need to change the implementation every time, it can receive a second parameter to receive a callback to determine the typecheck
2. no `as`, we can simply just use as when we use it, but I am thinking of let the typescript infer the type from the code. thanks

Comment: For 1, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXk0JW) meet your needs?  If so, I can write up an answer for it; if not, can you say what's wrong with it?

Comment: this is exactly what we are looking for, thanks! you can write the answer! we might need to pass the ItemType down?

Comment: What do you mean by "we might need to pass the ItemType down"?  I don't understand, sorry.